# NGINX Reverse Proxy A Port Between 2 Servers

Tags: nginx, port, reverse-proxy, icecast

Apologies if this is an obvious question, I've been reading up on NGINX and am hoping this is something I can use with my Icecast server.

Essentially I have the following setup:

```
ipAddress:8080 - Icecast Server (mount point is /stream)

domain.tld - Server running NGINX & hosting a PHP site.
```

What I'd like todo is take any requests to, for example, domain.tld:8000/stream and have it return what is actually ipAddress:8080/stream

Is this something NGINX can handle? Forgive me if I am missing something obvious, presently all I can find are guides on redirecting files to ports etc

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally not advisable to reverse-proxy Icecast. It breaks an array of things and if not configured properly can bring down your web server.

If you want to run Icecast on port 80, then I've explained this for Debian (and derivatives like Ubuntu) here: http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/icecast/2015-February/013198.html

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much - this will be a great help!

Comment: What does it break exactly? Mailing list reply is unclear, most of what is talked there is how to bind to port 80. Proxy_pass with disabled buffering and increases timeouts not enough to proxy this app?

Comment: You won't get the IP addresses of your listeners. There are some authentication gotchas. Trying to list the server on any YP directory will be very hard unless you know exactly what you are doing. There can be problems if the number of listeners approaches the proxying server connection limit. And a few other things that I probably can't remember right now.